# Can Select but not Insert from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: sql-server, mysql, linked-server, binlog

I'm having a problem with inserting data from SQL Server to MySQL. I saw this syntax that helped others:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server='MYSQL', @srvproduct='MySQL',
@provider='MSDASQL', @provstr='DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1
Driver};SERVER=HOST;Port=3306;USER=uid;PASSWORD=pw;OPTION=3;DATABASE=mydb;
```

but the error is still:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL1" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.44-MariaDB-log]Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.".
>
> Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL1" could not INSERT INTO table "[MSDASQL]".

It says here that the `BINLOG_FORMAT` is equal to `STATEMENT` but when I checked it, it is set to `MIXED`.

Found out a solution for these, they said that the `BINLOG_FORMAT` must be `ROW` but then I'm having a doubt or difficulty to edit in `my.cnf` because I don't know what will happen if I changed the binlog format from mixed to row.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found out a solution for these, they said that the `BINLOG_FORMAT` must be "ROW" but then I'm having a doubt or difficulty to edit in my.cnf because I don't know what will happen if I changed the binlog format from mixed to row.

Try it. If MySQL is going to eat your data, it's not going to care about that option -- it'll just plow forward regardless of your configuration. [`BINLOG_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log-setting.html) says explicitly

> If you are using InnoDB tables and the transaction isolation level is `READ COMMITTED` or `READ UNCOMMITTED`, only row-based logging can be used. It is possible to change the logging format to `STATEMENT`, but doing so at runtime leads very rapidly to errors because InnoDB can no longer perform inserts.

That means you have two options, either use the [default isolation level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) of `REPEATABLE READ` or set the option.

On a side note, [MySQL Isolation Levels are pretty borked and probably don't do what you want anyway](https://blog.pythian.com/understanding-mysql-isolation-levels-repeatable-read/)

Comment: Hi. I changed mixed to row and it is working. I continued it because of what you explained. Thank you very much